# Use javascript to find an html element which exists in an array of elements from the element's event

Tags: javascript

I have a table generated by javascript. When creating the tbody of the table I stored each element for each cell in an array. Any element is easily located by

```
let element = elements[r][c];
```

Where r and c are the row and column of the tbody.

When an event happens on the cell, like `keyup`, I capture the event and use `event.target` to retrieve the element the event was fired from.

```
event_element = event.target;
```

Is there now a way to find which element in the array `elements` is `event_element`?

Currently I am setting `element.name = element_rXcX` then parsing `event.target.name` to find values for `r` and `c` to recover the actual element in the array.

This also allows me to find the row and column of the cell in the table for an element's event.

I am assuming locating an element in the element array would be even better, and it may give me an aha moment understanding the DOM.

Keep in mind the element html may often be identical, however I noticed through the chrome javascript console that if I logged an element and clicked on it in the console it would highlight the correct cell in the table.

This makes me believe I must be able to look up the element in my element array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest `Array.find` like so:

```js
var arr = []
arr[0] = ["00", "01"];
arr[1] = ["10", "11"];
arr[2] = ["20", "21"];

function find(arr, element) {
  var col;
  var row;
  var tmpArr = arr.find(function(subArr){
    col = subArr.indexOf(element);
    return col > -1;
  });
  row = arr.indexOf(tmpArr);
  return [row, col];
}

console.log(find(arr, "21")); // [2,1]
```

Bear in mind that `array.find` is not supported by IE, so you would need to have a polyfill for it.

Comment: I guess I am confused by the DOM - it looks like when I log the element it shows as a string, but it appears to function as an object. Searching for a string would result in multiple possible results.

Comment: In that case you could use `data-` attribute while creating elements and store array coordinates there, something like this: `data-row=1 data-column=4`

Comment: I was just thinking that... and I was also thinking that I do need to code a unique id for each element to find it in the 2-d array. At that point I might as well stick with parsing the id or name, it ends up being less code

Comment: I had impression that you store actual elements in the array, not the strings? In that case searching the array should work. When using the function from my answer just pass `event.target` (or `currentTarget`) as a second argument instead of string.

Comment: yeah that totally works....so for all those searching for the darn tbody table row keeping track of the elements then putting the element though the code above actually works.... no delegation or closest etc....

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`event_element.cellIndex` and `event_element.parentNode.rowIndex`

> The cellIndex property returns the position of a cell in the cells collection of a table row.
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp
>
> The rowIndex property returns the position of a row in the rows collection of a table.
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp

Comment: For the row there is no guarantee regarding the parentNode. I have a check which lets me know if I need parentNode or parentNode.parentNode.

Comment: But I have the element, and I have an array of elements. The question is can i , and if so how do I locate the element in the array of elements?

Comment: What do you mean by locate the element in the array? elements[event_element.parentNode.rowIndex][event_element.cellIndex] doesn't work?

Comment: Input will need to go up two parent nodes, textNode will go up one. Then you have to find the number of rows on thead, which for me is also variable. This makes parsing the name of the element less code and more accurate. However, I have the element, and I have the array of elements. I am wondering if I can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505284/finding-index-of-value-in-two-dimensional-array-of-objects-in-javascript